# Releasing objects in viewWillDisappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

Is it safe to release the objects in viewWillDisappear? given that those objects will again be recreated on viewWillAppear.

So, this is how I am writing it. Is there any harm doing so?

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self releaseObjects];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)releaseObjects {
    self.request = nil;
    self.loadingOverlay = nil;
    self.textView = nil;
    self.label = nil;
    self.endPoint = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)iAnimated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:iAnimated];
    [self releaseObjects];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you release variables in the "companion" function of the one in which they were created.  So, if you create them in viewWillAppear, then you release them in viewWillDisappear.  viewWillLoad, releases in viewWillUnload, etc.

So yes, this is normal.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't break anything, but it might be wasteful... say the vc is on a tab and the user repeatedly switches between tabs.  You'll be doing a lot of extra free/alloc work.

Unless there's something unusually resource-consuming, I leave it to the OS to let me know that I should free memory with the hooks made for that purpose:  didReceiveMemoryWarning, dealloc, etc.

Comment: But isn't it like I am ending up creating auto-released objects every time user repeatedly switches between tabs. More over I do not see dealloc getting called ever after I dismiss a View Controller. I am doing this because I am seeing memory warning coming in my app - 2-3 times in a day!